# Быстрая отрисовка из списка обьектов на python

Tags: python, графика

Есть список координат и мне нужно в окошке 2000 на 2000 отрисовать точки на каждой координатах из списка.
Пробовал библиотеку turtle - отрисовывает, но очень медленно, а мне нужно в реальном времени так как координаты постоянно меняются. Есть ли функция чтобы отрисовывать мгновенно много объектов в turtle?
Или есть другая, более быстрая библиотека?
Отрисовывает по 10 объектов в секунду, а самих объектов может быть больше тысячи.
Может есть более простое решение с динамичной отрисовкой?

Вот код:

```
import random
from turtle import *

class Food():
    def __init__(self):
        self.xcor = random.randint(-100, 100)
        self.ycor = random.randint(-100, 100)
        
fods = []

for i in range(100):
    fods.append(Food())
    
ht()
up()
speed(0)

p = 0

while True:
    for i in fods:
        p += 1
        setpos(i.xcor, i.ycor)
        dot()
        print(p)
    clear()
```

Comment: `turtle` - это чисто учебная библиотека, для изучения азов. Для создания игр используйте `PyGame`, ну или другие библиотеки с продвинутым интерфейсом - `tkinter`, `Kyvi` и т.п., они должны гораздо быстрее графику отрисовывать.

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, подойдет ли вам этот вариант, но `matplotlib` отрисовал 2000 точек довольно быстро.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random


class Food():
    def __init__(self):
        self.xcor = random.randint(-100, 100)
        self.ycor = random.randint(-100, 100)


fods = []
for _ in range(2000):
    fods.append(Food())

x = [o.xcor for o in fods]
y = [o.ycor for o in fods]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 20), dpi=100)
ax = fig.add_subplot()
ax.scatter(x, y, c='#ff7f0e')
plt.show()
```

Comment: мне нужно каждую секунду отрисовывать по несколько кадров так как игра динамичная(хотя бы 30 кадров в секудну), как на этой библиотеке сделать много кадров?

Comment: Думаю, для этого она не подойдет

Comment: жаль, но я оптимизировал свой вариант и он отрисовывает 30 кадров в секунду при статичном изображении и если отрисовывет очень часто то фпс снижается, никак не могу понять как оптимизировать еще лучше. Может есть способ ускорить работу цикла for?
сам сервер не лагает так как в консоль постоянно выводится состояние обьектов, именно отрисовка очень сильно провисает.